# Ошибка запуска программы на Android

Tags: android

Не важно, на эмуляторе или на устройстве, программа падает с ошибкой:

> Uploading file local path: D:\XPN\XPN_GAME\proj.android-studio\app\build\outputs\apk\XPN_GAME-debug.apk remote path: /data/local/tmp/XPN_proj Installing XPN_proj DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/XPN_proj" pkg: /data/local/tmp/XPN_proj Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK] DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm uninstall XPN_proj Unknown failure

С устройством все нормально, потому что есть другая программа, того же типа и она работает.

Файлы для android создал  cocos2d-x, он кривой и делает кучу ошибок при генерации файлов.

Где искать ошибку?

Comment: `INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK` означает, что у вас корявый APK-файл. Что-то с ним не так.

Comment: ну это понятно, но от того мне не легче, я не знаю где найти проблему.

Comment: А девайс/эмулятор подходит по уровню API к приложению?

Comment: Я не знаю, все создавал cocos2d-x. И мне уже пришлось переписать несколько файлов. Я даже не знаю где точно искать ошибку ...